# How to specify borders in urwid?

Tags: python-3.x, urwid

I am new to urwid and think I missunderstood something. I don't see why this doesn't work. And I don't understand the error message.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import urwid

def show_or_exit(key):
    if key in ('q', 'Q'):
        raise urwid.ExitMainLoop()
    txt.set_text(repr(key))

txt = urwid.Text('FooBar')

fil = urwid.Filler(txt, valign='middle', height=('relative', 70))
box = urwid.LineBox(fil)
pad = urwid.Padding(box, align='center', width=('relative', 85))

loop = urwid.MainLoop(pad, unhandled_input=show_or_exit)
loop.run()
```

Comment: how do want the border to look? Did you try to put the padding widget inside another linebox .

Comment: I simply want a border on all four sides. But I think this question is a good way to find deeper understand of the urwid concept. Of course I read the manual and about the difference between Flow and Box widgets. But I think I didn't get into it really.

Comment: I found this link helpful.  Apparently this error happens *a lot*: https://github.com/urwid/urwid/wiki/FAQ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've also had problems like this, to get a better grasp of what's going on you probably should read [the documentation section about widgets sizing modes](http://urwid.org/manual/widgets.html#box-flow-and-fixed-widgets). Basically, this has to do with the way the widgets rendering work, which is different for each widget depending on its "sizing mode". This is one of the trickiest things to understand about Urwid, once you get that then you're able to be more productive with it. :)

Here is a working version of the code you provided:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import urwid


def show_or_exit(key):
    if key in ('q', 'Q'):
        raise urwid.ExitMainLoop()
    txt.set_text(repr(key))


txt = urwid.Text('FooBar')
widget = urwid.LineBox(txt)
widget = urwid.Padding(widget, align='center', width=('relative', 85))
widget = urwid.Filler(widget, 'middle')

loop = urwid.MainLoop(widget, unhandled_input=show_or_exit)
loop.run()
```